How to panzoom an iframe in Fancybox?
I wonder if Fancybox supports panzoom of iframes. For example, in the following code, I can add the option to add panzoom effect to images, but I am not sure how to make iframe also act the same? I followed the similar syntax by adding "Iframes" in the options but it did not work.
<a href="https://fancyapps.com/iframe.html" data-type="iframe" data-fancybox="gallery" data-caption="Caption #1">
        <img src="https://lipsum.app/id/1/200x150" />
</a>

<a href="https://lipsum.app/id/2/800x600" data-fancybox="gallery" data-caption="Caption #2">
        <img src="https://lipsum.app/id/2/200x150" />
</a>

<script>
    Fancybox.bind("[data-fancybox]", {
        Images: {
            Panzoom: {
                maxScale: 2,
            },
        },
        Iframes: {
            Panzoom: {
                maxScale: 2,
            },
        },
        // Your custom options
    });
</script>


You could do that in two steps:

create Panzoom instance on your page where iframe is used for the content example - https://jsfiddle.net/38dLebov/
add Fancybox and display your previously created HTML element as "inline content", example - https://jsfiddle.net/tyqx5dap/

<div id="dialog-content" style="display:none;max-width:500px;">
  <div class="f-panzoom" id="myPanzoom">
    <iframe allow="autoplay; fullscreen" scrolling="auto" src="https://fancyapps.com/iframe.html"></iframe>
  </div>
</div>
<p>
  <button data-fancybox data-src="#dialog-content">Launch Dialog</button>
</p>



<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <link
          rel="stylesheet"
          href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fancyapps/ui@5.0/dist/panzoom/panzoom.css"
          />
    <link
          rel="stylesheet"
          href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fancyapps/ui@5.0/dist/panzoom/panzoom.toolbar.css"
          />
    <link
          rel="stylesheet"
          href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fancyapps/ui@5.0/dist/fancybox/fancybox.css"
          />
    <style>
      #myPanzoom {
        max-width:600px;
        height: 400px;
        background: #eee;
      }

      #myPanzoom iframe {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <div id="dialog-content" style="display:none;max-width:500px;">
        <div class="f-panzoom" id="myPanzoom">
          <iframe allow="autoplay; fullscreen" scrolling="auto" src="https://fancyapps.com/iframe.html"></iframe>
        </div>
      </div>
      <p>
        <button data-fancybox data-src="#dialog-content">Launch Dialog</button>
      </p>
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fancyapps/ui@5.0/dist/panzoom/panzoom.umd.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fancyapps/ui@5.0/dist/panzoom/panzoom.toolbar.umd.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fancyapps/ui@5.0/dist/fancybox/fancybox.umd.js"></script>
    <script>
      new Panzoom(document.getElementById("myPanzoom"), {
        width : 800, 
        height: 800,
        Toolbar: {
          display: ["zoomIn", "zoomOut"],
        },
      }, {
        Toolbar
      });

      Fancybox.bind('[data-fancybox]', {
        // Custom options for all galleries
      });    
    </script>
  </body>
</html>




Thanks! So there is no easy way to panzoom iframe by just adding an option in Fancybox, I have to use Panzoom explicitly?

I ended using a different package https://www.npmjs.com/package/@panzoom/panzoom to find the current slide and directly apply panzoom effect on the iframe, so I don't need to add 2 level wrappers to the iframe. The panzoom effect is as good.
